# How to transmit data between two pages in a React CRUD app with Edit and Delete buttons

Tags: reactjs

React curd app send that data of input files one webpage in to the table of another webpage along that edit and delete buttons.after submission of data should present another webpage nothing should be there send the data of inputs filed one webpage to another webpage

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.